# Excel VBA: Get the Workbook associated with a range

Tags: excel, copy, range, vba

This macro needs to start selecting data from various sheets on a user-selected workbook. In other words, I do not know the name of the workbook beforehand. I am asking the user to select a cell in another already open file, so that I can start grabbing data from that book.

```
Set bookRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a cell in the sheet from which you wish to import data", Type:=8)
bookName = bookRange.GET_WORKBOOK_NAME_SOMEHOW
```

Does something like `GET_WORKBOOK_NAME_SOMEHOW` exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a *Range* it is easy to get the name of the *Sheet* the range is on and the name of the *Workbook* the sheet is on.:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick a range", Type:=8)
    MsgBox r.Address & vbCrLf & r.Parent.Name & vbCrLf & r.Parent.Parent.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: I noticed recently that there's even a `Range.Worksheet` property.